# Camera setup logic iOS

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

Although i've searched SO and read documentation multiple times on `AVCaptureConnection`,  `AVCaptureSession`, `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, `AVCaptureDevice`, `AVCaptureInput/Output`  … i'm still confused about all this AV stuff. When it comes to this, it's one big pile of abstract words to me, that don't make much sense. I'm asking to shed some light on the subject for me here.

So, can anyone explain coherently in *plain english* the logic of proper setup and use of the media devices? What is AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? What is AVCaptureConnection? Input/Output?

I want to catch the basic idea the people who made this stuff had while making it.

Thanks

Comment: This question would be better phrased as "I'm trying to do X, I don't understand these parts". As it stands you're asking people to rewrite the docs for you - it's a bit too broad.

Comment: @jrturton no, i'm asking for guidance in understanding the logic of how media devices are properly set up and used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish I had more time to write a more thorough reply.  Here are some simplified basics:

In order to work with audio and video coming from the hardware, destined for the screen or files, you need to setup an AVCaptureSession that helps coordinate the sources and the destinations, using AVCaptureConnections.  You use the session instance to start and stop the process, along with setting some output properties like bitrate and quality.  You use the AVCaptureConnection instance(s) to control the connection between an AVCaptureInputPort and an AVCaptureOutputPort (or AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer), such as monitoring input levels of sounds or setting the orientation of the video.

AVCaptureInputPort are different inputs from AVCaptureDevice - which is where your video or audio is coming from, such as the camera or the microphone.  You will normally look through all available devices and choose those that have the properties you are looking for, such as if they are audio, or if they are the front-facing camera.

AVCaptureOutput is where the AV is sent - it might be a file or a routine that allows you to process the data in real-time, etc.

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is an OpenGL layer that is optimized for very fast rendering of the output of the selected video input device (front or back camera).  You typically use this to show your user what input you are working with - sort of like a camera viewfinder.

If you are going to use this stuff, then you must read Apple's [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html)

Here's an image that may help you some more (from above-mentioned doc):  [image]

A more detailed view: [image]

Comment: Thanks for the solid and clear answer. I get it now. Hopefully it will help somebody else seeking for entire thing explained in one place. Accepted.

Comment: Yes, if anyone starts just with Apple's sample code, they can get woefully lost in all the AVCaptureXXX terminology.  Best to start with these images and then read the AV Foundation doc.